# If I create two std::thread, how can I identify which thread ends first

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous, stdthread

I want to create two `std::thread` processes.  Then I want to figure out which thread ended first and end the other thread if it is still running (probably by calling its destructor?).  I would like to only use the std libraries.  I'm guessing I need to do something with `std::atomic` and/or `std::future`, or implement a callback?

```cpp
int process1( void ); 
int process2( void ); 

std::thread first (process1() );
std::thread second (process2() );

//check which thread is done first and call join() on that thread to end it nicely?
//kill the other thread if its not done or call join() if it is done?
```

Comment: Why not just have a single `std::atomic` or `std::conditional_variable` that both threads look at? Set/signal that variable when either thread ends. You need to `join()` both threads, don't kill threads.

Comment: Because killing threads often leads to unstable processes. Depending on what was going on in the thread at the time of killing, maybe you'll be OK. Maybe you won't. Killing a thread is a last resort, and you may be better off killing the whole program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just end a thread from outside the thread itself. You have to signal the thread in some way that it needs to stop. You can do this with a `std::atomic_bool`for example.

Something like this:

```
// thread-safe output
#define con_sync_out(m) do{std::ostringstream o; o<<m<<'\n'; std::cout<<o.str();}while(0)
#define con_sync_err(m) do{std::ostringstream o; o<<m<<'\n'; std::cerr<<o.str();}while(0)

// random numbers
template<typename Integer>
Integer random(Integer lo, Integer hi)
{
    thread_local std::mt19937 mt{std::random_device{}()};
    return std::uniform_int_distribution<Integer>(lo, hi)(mt);
}
    
// stuff to do
void do_work(char const* id, int a, int b, std::atomic_bool& done)
{
    // check if done == true (signal to stop)
    while(!done && a < b)
    {
        ++a;
        con_sync_out(id << ": " << a << "/" << b);
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(random<int>(500, 1000)));
    }

    done = true;
}


int main()
{

    std::atomic_bool done = false; // signal flag

    std::thread t1(do_work, "A", random<int>(0, 10), random<int>(10, 20), std::ref(done));
    std::thread t2(do_work, "B", random<int>(0, 10), random<int>(10, 20), std::ref(done));

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no standard/easy way to kill a thread in C++. They're not like processes.

Either detach() them both and wait in your main thread for a `std::conditional_variable` notification from the fastest thread if you don't mind letting the slower one finish in the background.

Or join() them both and periodically check for the `std::conditional_variable` in each thread to notify that the other one has finished, and then abort by returning earlier.

If neither join() nor detach() have been called before a non-empty `std::thread` is destroyed, then the program simply terminates.